# Datatable jquery serverside only work on the load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatable

I search in all web,i.e Google, datatable docs, datatable .. and not found the solution.
I use Symfony 4 and follow this text, https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html and https://datatables.net/manual/server-side. Then my code is that:

```
  <html>
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable_info">
                              <thead>
                              <tr class="headings">
                                  <th></th>
                                  <th class="column-title">N&uacute;mero/Ano</th>
                                  <th class="column-title">Cadastrado em</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
  <script>
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
                "serverSide": true,
                "info": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "ajax":{
                    "url":"/decreto/filter",
                    "type": "GET"
                },
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
                },
                "lengthMenu": [ 5, 10, 15, 25 ],
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "data":           null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "number",
                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            var z = "";
                            data = data.toString();
                            for (;(4-data.length)>z.length;z = z.concat("0"));

                            return  z+data+"/"+row.year;
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "data":"registry.date",
                        "render": function ( data ) {
                            var dMy = data.split(" ")[0].split("-");
                            var time = data.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0];

                            return dMy[2]+"/"+dMy[1]+"/"+dMy[0]+" "+time;
                        },
                    },
],
              //*/
              "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            } );
</script>
```

My Controller return that:

```
    $source = $request->query->get("search")["value"];
    $rows = $request->query->get("length");
....
return new JsonResponse(
        array(
            'draw'=>intval(1),
            'recordsTotal'=>intval($em->total()["total"]),
            'recordsFiltered'=>intval(count($list)),
            'data'=>$list,
        )
    );
```

When the page load at first time, this work fine, return only 5 rows like I define. But if I try to filter, don't work. 
For debug what was send, I change the method in Symfony, switch GET for Post, and return an error with the URL:

```
    jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/decreto/filter?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=number&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=registry.date&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=files&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=5&search%5Bvalue%5D=el&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1520304436769 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Then I fix the method to filter the request sent, was send :

```
DecretoController.php on line 194:
array:7 [▼
  "draw" => "1"
  "columns" => array:5 [▶]
  "order" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
  ]
  "start" => "0"
  "length" => "5"
  "search" => array:2 [▼
      "value" => "el"
      "regex" => "false"
   ]
  "_" => "1520302968156"
  ]
```

The content is like says https://datatables.net/manual/server-side.
Oh right then, and continuous with the says the site above, my controller returned:

```
DecretoController.php on line 224:
array:4 [▼
  "draw" => 1
  "recordsTotal" => 6
  "recordsFiltered" => 1
  "data" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:13 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Data has 1 element, the match with i lookup. Until then, fine! The fine, finish here. Make the jsonResponse the change for:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":6,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":
[{"id":"XYgrQvzrYrYY","number":2,"year":2018,"publish":{"date":"2018-01-11 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"created":{"date":"2018-01-02 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"description":"asfasfasdfasdfsadfsadfsd (admitido pelo sdfasdf), o sr. sfasdfasfas.","registry":{"date":"2018-03-02 02:04:22.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"active":1,"user_id":1,"user_first_name":"Eu,"unidade_id":7,"unidade_name":"Co do Munic\u00edpio","files":[]}]}
```

What's wrong? 
- Load at first page OK
- Search is working
- Return like order on documentation

I use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Thanks ..
:(

Answer (score 1):

because you have fixed draw value, which should be sequence for every request.

explaination:

first load. datatables request draw=1. php return draw=1 . this works fine.

if you do any action (sort, search, filter etc). datatables will request draw=2. php return draw=1. error happened. because request draw is not match with response draw

try change `'draw'=>intval(1),` to `'draw'=>intval($_GET['draw']),`

Comment: OMG, this is it! Its correct! Thank you @plonknimbuz. Five hours wasted yesterday... :)

Comment: welcome. dont forget to check as answer to help other people who have same trouble

Comment: once again. dont forget to filter all your input ($_GET) or using prepare statement before send it to db